# Magento 2 - check if category have description

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, php, category

I want to add a new text only if category have description. How I can check in phtml if category description contain text?

Comment: On which page you are trying to check this condition?

Comment: Magento_Catalog/templates/category/description.phtml

Comment: You want to add new text after category description or before ?

Comment: I think will be before description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Magento_Catalog/templates/category/description.phtml` there is already an if clause which checks if a category has a description so what is the problem? Just add new code inside of the template.

Comment: You have right, thank you very much, I really don't see it :)

Answer (score 0):

This **if** statement is already checking for category description.

```
<?php if ($_description = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description">
        // Add you new text here...
        <?php echo "New TEXT"; ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere in custom phtml file :

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currentCategory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category information

echo $currentCategory->getDescription();

?>
```